# How to get rid of blue color when a row is selected in TStringGrid?

Tags: vcl, tstringgrid, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to learn drawing a StringGrid in Delphi.

Here is my StringGrid:

[image: My StringGrid's Picture]

But the problem is when I select a row blue areas appear like shown in the image even I did not set color to blue.

I want to make selected row fully orange and get rid of dotted lines.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What version? Fmx or vcl?

Comment: @ThomasRiedel I have used VCL framework. Then I have skinned it.

Comment: Sounds like the grid is drawing its default blue highlight first, and then you are drawing your own colors on top of that, but are not drawing everywhere that the default was drawn. Do you have the `DefaultDrawing` property set to true or false? Is the `GridLineWidth` property set to 0 or more than 0? Do you have the `goFixedVertLine`/`goVertLine` flags enabled in the `Options` property? The `TRect` provided by the `OnDrawCell` event does not include the spaces/gridlines between cells, so you would have to account for that if you want to draw over top of them.